# Using Automapper to map entity framework classes to business classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have the following two classes generated by Entity Framework:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string namen { get; set; }
    public int house { get; set; }
    [IgnoreMap]
    public virtual House House1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class House
{
    public House()
    {
        this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Then I also have these two similar classes in my Business Layer:

```
public class House
{        
    public House()
    {
        this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string namen { get; set; }
    public int house { get; set; }        
}
```

Pretty much the same, hugh?
In my Business Layer I read a List of houses from the Database. Then I map the whole list to a list of my Business house class using Automapper:

```
    public List<elci.BusinessEntities.House> getHouses()
    {
        YardEntities cx = new YardEntities();
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.House, BusinessEntities.House>());

        List<DataAccessLayer.House> dhl = cx.Houses.ToList();
        List<BusinessEntities.House> bhl = Mapper.Map<List<DataAccessLayer.House>, List<BusinessEntities.House>>(dhl);
        return bhl;
    }
```

However, in the following line I get a runtime exception:

```
 Mapper.Map<List<DataAccessLayer.House>, List<BusinessEntities.House>>(dhl);
```

"Error mapping types".

I guess, that this might be, because every Person points to a House and every House points to Persons. Because I do not need this "circle" in my BusinessLayer I decorated this attribute with [IgnoreMap], but without any success. The error still remains.

Any suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you remove `IgnoreMap` attribute. Is it working?

Comment: `Error Mapping Types` error also gives  what types are not mapped. can you get into the inner exception details and paste it here.

Comment: Also, you need to create a `mapper` for `Person` entities explicitly as they are referenced in `House` Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this eventually fixed my issue:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<List<House>, List<HouseViewModel>>();
            cfg.CreateMap<List<Person>, List<PersonViewModel>>();
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the error remains without ignoremap. 
The inner exception tells me the following:

```
{"Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nList`1 -> List`1\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[elci.DataAccessLayer.House, DataAccessLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[elci.BusinessEntities.House, BusinessEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
```

So the House-Type is the problem. 
I also tried to add another map:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.House, BusinessEntities.House>());
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DataAccessLayer.Person, BusinessEntities.Person>());
```

without success and the same error. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
config.CreateMap<TSource,TDestination>().PreserveReferences()
```

You have circular references Person->House->ICollection

**Circular references**

Previously, AutoMapper could handle circular references by keeping track of what was mapped, and on every mapping, check a local hashtable of source/destination objects to see if the item was already mapped. It turns out this tracking is very expensive, and you need to opt-in using PreserveReferences for circular maps to work. Alternatively, you can configure MaxDepth:

```
// Self-referential mapping
cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>().MaxDepth(3);
// Circular references between users and groups
cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>().PreserveReferences();
```

[AutoMapper docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html)

Comment: As links can break, please include the relevant part of the linked page in the answer.

Comment: That's not needed anymore. The docs continue with `Starting from 6.1.0 PreserveReferences is set automatically at config time whenever the recursion can be detected statically.`.